# 2-letter state abbreviation for Android Place

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-geocoder

How can you get the two-letter state abbreviation from a [Place](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) returned by the Google APIs for Android for places in the US?

[Geocoder.getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) provides the full state name in [Address.getAdminArea](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAdminArea()). Is there a to convert the state name to its abbreviation? Or a solution that doesn't involve `Geocoder` at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining State abbreviation from getAdminArea();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879882/obtaining-state-abbreviation-from-getadminarea)

Comment: That question is specific to `Geocoder`. This question is broader. A geocoder-based answer would solve the problem, but there isn't currently a clean answer. Since we're starting from a `Place`, there may be solution not related to `Geocoder` that will do a better job.